# Is using Pseudo-Random number generator different from real random number in Markov chain Monte-Carlo?

Tags: machine-learning, probability, markov-chains

I want to use matlab to do MCMC approximation to a probability distribution. However, I found out there is a lot of noise compared with theoretical results.

My question is, is it possible that the noise comes from the Pseudo- random number generators  in matlab itself?

Comment: You definitely have to be more specific. What kind of noise? Can you give your code and your theoretical reasoning? Random generators are extremely well researched and tested to be unbiased and that the generated sequences indeed follow a uniform distribution. So it's hard to believe that in your case random numbers are not random enough.

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule, one doesn't get a close agreement between any form of Monte Carlo simulation and a theoretical probability distribution unless one uses a very large number of samples. Typically, one would expect that the "noise" you observe will decrease only as slowly as one over the square-root of the number of samples (i.e. 100 times more samples might be needed to reduce the noise by a factor of about 10). In very particular circumstances one may find that a simple random number generator (e.g. linear congruential) may not be appropriate for generating points uniformly over a high-dimensional space, but it's probably worth thinking about the effects of Monte-Carlo sampling before worrying about the quality of the random-number generator itself. Obviously, without specific details of your application it's difficult to be more specific.